# Access Violation when Assigning SOAP Property - Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi

I generated an Interface file using XE2's WSDL Wizard (Interface file appears at bottom of this listing)

When I try to assign the "begin_" property of myPaxActivity at runtime I get an A/V and don't understand why.

It appears to me that I have instantiated a myPaxActivity object and I think I should be able to assign a value to the .begin_ property.

Any help appreciated,  TIA

I'm running Delphi XE2, Update 3, WinXP (sp3).

Here is my code (see ~ ln 60):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  ScheduleUploadV2, Soap.InvokeRegistry, Soap.Rio, Soap.SOAPHTTPClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnTest: TButton;
    HTTPRIO1: THTTPRIO;
    procedure btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SendToAvinode();

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendToAvinode;
end;


procedure TForm1.SendToAvinode;
var
  myAviSchedContainer : ScheduleContainerType;
  Uploader          : ScheduleUploadV2WS;
  WSResponse        : StatusType;

  myPlane           : AircraftType;
  mySched           : ScheduleType;
  myPaxActivity     : PAXActivityType;
  arrSched          : Array_Of_ScheduleType;  //array[0..1] of ScheduleType;

  ErrorCount, i : Integer;
  ThisError : ErrorType;
  ErrAccum: string;

begin
   myAviSchedContainer := ScheduleContainerType.Create;
   mySched             := ScheduleType.Create;
   myPlane             := AircraftType.Create;
   myPaxActivity       := PAXActivityType.Create;

   // Aircraft
   myPlane.tail := 'CL-001';
   mySched.aircraft := myPlane;

   // Passenger Activity
   myPaxActivity.vendorCode   := 'TestVCode';

       // ***** Next line causes A/V ??? *******
   myPaxActivity.begin_.AsDateTime := StrToDateTime('05/21/2012 09:00') ; // <--

   myPaxActivity.startAirport.icaoCode := 'KLAX';
   myPaxActivity.endAirport.icaoCode   := 'KTEB';
   myPaxActivity.pax := 2;
   mySched.paxActivity[0] := myPaxActivity;

   myAviSchedContainer.schedule[0] := mySched;

   // issue request w/ user authentication
   HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.UserName := 'integrationcl';
   HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.Password := 'devpass2';
   Uploader   := GetScheduleUploadV2WS(False, '', HTTPRIO1);
   WSResponse := Uploader.request(myAviSchedContainer);

   ErrorCount := SizeOf(WSResponse.errors);
   for i := 0 to ErrorCount do begin
     ThisError := WSResponse.errors[i];
     ErrAccum := ErrAccum + ThisError.message_ + '||';
   end;

   ShowMessage('Error List ' + ErrAccum);

   myPaxActivity.Free;
   myPlane.Free;
   mySched.Free;
   myAviSchedContainer.Free;
end;

end.
```

Here is the Interface file generated by the WSDL Wizard (I truncated the getter/setter section to keep this post within the 30,000 char limit):

```
unit ScheduleUploadV2;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_UNBD = $0002;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_ATTR = $0010;
  IS_TEXT = $0020;


type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:boolean         - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:duration        - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:date            - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:int             - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:decimal         - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:long            - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:dateTime        - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]

  ContactInfoType      = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  ActivityFBOType      = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  ActivityRegulationType = class;               { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  ActivityState        = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  ScheduleContainerType = class;                { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  CompanyType          = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  AircraftType         = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  ErrorType            = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  StatusType           = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  AirportType          = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  ArgusRatingType      = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  DistanceType         = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  InsuranceType        = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }
  ScheduleType         = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  AbstractActivityType = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  GuaranteeActivityType = class;                { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  GenericActivityType  = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  PAXActivityType      = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblCplx] }
  MonetaryType         = class;                 { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblCplx] }

  {$SCOPEDENUMS ON}
  { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblSmpl] }
  FBOSourceType = (UNIVERSAL, ACUKWIK, OWN, OTHER);

  { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblSmpl] }
  ErrorCodeType = (
      S0, 
      S1, 
      A0,
      A1, 
      A2, 
      A3,
      A4, 
      A5, 
      I0, 
      I1, 
      I2, 
      I3, 
      B0
  );

  { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblSmpl] }
  StatusCodeType = (S, F, PS);

  { "http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes"[GblSmpl] }
  DistanceUnitType = (NM, MI, KM);

  {$SCOPEDENUMS OFF}

  Array_Of_GuaranteeActivityType = array of GuaranteeActivityType;   { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblUbnd] }
  Array_Of_ScheduleType = array of ScheduleType;   { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblUbnd] }
  Array_Of_PAXActivityType = array of PAXActivityType;   { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblUbnd] }
  Array_Of_GenericActivityType = array of GenericActivityType;   { "http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload"[GblUbnd] }



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : ActivityFBOType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  ActivityFBOType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FfboSource: FBOSourceType;
    FfboId: string;
    FfboId_Specified: boolean;
    FfboName: string;
    procedure SetfboId(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  fboId_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property fboSource: FBOSourceType  read FfboSource write FfboSource;
    property fboId:     string         Index (IS_OPTN) read FfboId write SetfboId stored fboId_Specified;
    property fboName:   string         read FfboName write FfboName;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : ActivityRegulationType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  ActivityRegulationType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fcode: string;
    Fdescription: string;
  published
    property code:        string  read Fcode write Fcode;
    property description: string  read Fdescription write Fdescription;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : ActivityState, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  ActivityState = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FvendorId: string;
    Fclear: Boolean;
  published
    property vendorId: string   read FvendorId write FvendorId;
    property clear:    Boolean  read Fclear write Fclear;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : ScheduleContainerType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  ScheduleContainerType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fproduct: string;
    Fschedule: Array_Of_ScheduleType;
    Fschedule_Specified: boolean;
    procedure Setschedule(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_ScheduleType: Array_Of_ScheduleType);
    function  schedule_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property product:  string                 read Fproduct write Fproduct;
    property schedule: Array_Of_ScheduleType  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL) read Fschedule write Setschedule stored schedule_Specified;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : CompanyType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes
  // ************************************************************************ //
  CompanyType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fname_: string;
    FcertificateNumber: string;
    FcertificateNumber_Specified: boolean;
    Fcode: string;
    Fcode_Specified: boolean;
    FcontactInfo: ContactInfoType;
    FcontactInfo_Specified: boolean;
    FargusRating: ArgusRatingType;
    FargusRating_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SetcertificateNumber(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  certificateNumber_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setcode(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  code_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetcontactInfo(Index: Integer; const AContactInfoType: ContactInfoType);
    function  contactInfo_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetargusRating(Index: Integer; const AArgusRatingType: ArgusRatingType);
    function  argusRating_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property name_:             string           read Fname_ write Fname_;
    property certificateNumber: string           Index (IS_OPTN) read FcertificateNumber write SetcertificateNumber stored certificateNumber_Specified;
    property code:              string           Index (IS_OPTN) read Fcode write Setcode stored code_Specified;
    property contactInfo:       ContactInfoType  Index (IS_OPTN) read FcontactInfo write SetcontactInfo stored contactInfo_Specified;
    property argusRating:       ArgusRatingType  Index (IS_OPTN) read FargusRating write SetargusRating stored argusRating_Specified;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : AircraftType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes
  // ************************************************************************ //
  AircraftType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Ftail: string;
    Fmodel: string;
    Fmodel_Specified: boolean;
    FyearOfMake: string;
    FyearOfMake_Specified: boolean;
    FinteriorRefurbished: TXSDate;
    FinteriorRefurbished_Specified: boolean;
    FexteriorRefurbished: TXSDate;
    FexteriorRefurbished_Specified: boolean;
    FmaxPAX: Integer;
    FmaxPAX_Specified: boolean;
    Foperator: CompanyType;
    Foperator_Specified: boolean;
    FhomeBase: AirportType;
    FhomeBase_Specified: boolean;
    FminimumDayUsage: TXSDuration;
    FminimumDayUsage_Specified: boolean;
    FminimumLegUsage: TXSDuration;
    FminimumLegUsage_Specified: boolean;
    Fequipment: Array_Of_string;
    Fequipment_Specified: boolean;
    Frange: DistanceType;
    Frange_Specified: boolean;
    Finsurance: InsuranceType;
    Finsurance_Specified: boolean;
    FtotalTimeAirframe: Integer;
    FtotalTimeAirframe_Specified: boolean;
    procedure Setmodel(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  model_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetyearOfMake(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  yearOfMake_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetinteriorRefurbished(Index: Integer; const ATXSDate: TXSDate);
    function  interiorRefurbished_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetexteriorRefurbished(Index: Integer; const ATXSDate: TXSDate);
    function  exteriorRefurbished_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetmaxPAX(Index: Integer; const AInteger: Integer);
    function  maxPAX_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setoperator(Index: Integer; const ACompanyType: CompanyType);
    function  operator_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SethomeBase(Index: Integer; const AAirportType: AirportType);
    function  homeBase_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetminimumDayUsage(Index: Integer; const ATXSDuration: TXSDuration);
    function  minimumDayUsage_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetminimumLegUsage(Index: Integer; const ATXSDuration: TXSDuration);
    function  minimumLegUsage_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setequipment(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_string: Array_Of_string);
    function  equipment_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setrange(Index: Integer; const ADistanceType: DistanceType);
    function  range_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setinsurance(Index: Integer; const AInsuranceType: InsuranceType);
    function  insurance_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SettotalTimeAirframe(Index: Integer; const AInteger: Integer);
    function  totalTimeAirframe_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property tail:                string           read Ftail write Ftail;
    property model:               string           Index (IS_OPTN) read Fmodel write Setmodel stored model_Specified;
    property yearOfMake:          string           Index (IS_OPTN) read FyearOfMake write SetyearOfMake stored yearOfMake_Specified;
    property interiorRefurbished: TXSDate          Index (IS_OPTN) read FinteriorRefurbished write SetinteriorRefurbished stored interiorRefurbished_Specified;
    property exteriorRefurbished: TXSDate          Index (IS_OPTN) read FexteriorRefurbished write SetexteriorRefurbished stored exteriorRefurbished_Specified;
    property maxPAX:              Integer          Index (IS_OPTN) read FmaxPAX write SetmaxPAX stored maxPAX_Specified;
    property operator:            CompanyType      Index (IS_OPTN) read Foperator write Setoperator stored operator_Specified;
    property homeBase:            AirportType      Index (IS_OPTN) read FhomeBase write SethomeBase stored homeBase_Specified;
    property minimumDayUsage:     TXSDuration      Index (IS_OPTN) read FminimumDayUsage write SetminimumDayUsage stored minimumDayUsage_Specified;
    property minimumLegUsage:     TXSDuration      Index (IS_OPTN) read FminimumLegUsage write SetminimumLegUsage stored minimumLegUsage_Specified;
    property equipment:           Array_Of_string  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL) read Fequipment write Setequipment stored equipment_Specified;
    property range:               DistanceType     Index (IS_OPTN) read Frange write Setrange stored range_Specified;
    property insurance:           InsuranceType    Index (IS_OPTN) read Finsurance write Setinsurance stored insurance_Specified;
    property totalTimeAirframe:   Integer          Index (IS_OPTN) read FtotalTimeAirframe write SettotalTimeAirframe stored totalTimeAirframe_Specified;
  end;

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : StatusType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes
  // ************************************************************************ //
  StatusType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fcode: StatusCodeType;
    Ferrors: ErrorContainerType;
    Ferrors_Specified: boolean;
    procedure Seterrors(Index: Integer; const AErrorContainerType: ErrorContainerType);
    function  errors_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property code:   StatusCodeType      read Fcode write Fcode;
    property errors: ErrorContainerType  Index (IS_OPTN) read Ferrors write Seterrors stored errors_Specified;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : AirportType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/core/CommonTypes
  // ************************************************************************ //
  AirportType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FfubarId: Int64;
    FfubarId_Specified: boolean;
    FicaoCode: string;
    FicaoCode_Specified: boolean;
    FiataCode: string;
    FiataCode_Specified: boolean;
    FfaaCode: string;
    FfaaCode_Specified: boolean;
    Fname_: string;
    Fname__Specified: boolean;
    Fcity: string;
    Fcity_Specified: boolean;
    Fcountry: string;
    Fcountry_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SetfubarId(Index: Integer; const AInt64: Int64);
    function  fubarId_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SeticaoCode(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  icaoCode_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetiataCode(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  iataCode_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetfaaCode(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  faaCode_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setname_(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  name__Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setcity(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  city_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setcountry(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  country_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property fubarId: Int64   Index (IS_ATTR or IS_OPTN) read FfubarId write SetfubarId stored fubarId_Specified;
    property icaoCode:  string  Index (IS_OPTN) read FicaoCode write SeticaoCode stored icaoCode_Specified;
    property iataCode:  string  Index (IS_OPTN) read FiataCode write SetiataCode stored iataCode_Specified;
    property faaCode:   string  Index (IS_OPTN) read FfaaCode write SetfaaCode stored faaCode_Specified;
    property name_:     string  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fname_ write Setname_ stored name__Specified;
    property city:      string  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fcity write Setcity stored city_Specified;
    property country:   string  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fcountry write Setcountry stored country_Specified;
  end;


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : ScheduleType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  ScheduleType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fclear: Boolean;
    Faircraft: AircraftType;
    Fbegin_: TXSDateTime;
    Fbegin__Specified: boolean;
    Fend_: TXSDateTime;
    Fend__Specified: boolean;
    Fguarantee: Array_Of_GuaranteeActivityType;
    Fguarantee_Specified: boolean;
    Factivity: Array_Of_GenericActivityType;
    Factivity_Specified: boolean;
    FpaxActivity: Array_Of_PAXActivityType;
    FpaxActivity_Specified: boolean;
    procedure Setbegin_(Index: Integer; const ATXSDateTime: TXSDateTime);
    function  begin__Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setend_(Index: Integer; const ATXSDateTime: TXSDateTime);
    function  end__Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setguarantee(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_GuaranteeActivityType: Array_Of_GuaranteeActivityType);
    function  guarantee_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setactivity(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_GenericActivityType: Array_Of_GenericActivityType);
    function  activity_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SetpaxActivity(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_PAXActivityType: Array_Of_PAXActivityType);
    function  paxActivity_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property clear:       Boolean                         read Fclear write Fclear;
    property aircraft:    AircraftType                    read Faircraft write Faircraft;
    property begin_:      TXSDateTime                     Index (IS_OPTN) read Fbegin_ write Setbegin_ stored begin__Specified;
    property end_:        TXSDateTime                     Index (IS_OPTN) read Fend_ write Setend_ stored end__Specified;
    property guarantee:   Array_Of_GuaranteeActivityType  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL) read Fguarantee write Setguarantee stored guarantee_Specified;
    property activity:    Array_Of_GenericActivityType    Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL) read Factivity write Setactivity stored activity_Specified;
    property paxActivity: Array_Of_PAXActivityType        Index (IS_OPTN or IS_UNBD or IS_NLBL) read FpaxActivity write SetpaxActivity stored paxActivity_Specified;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : AbstractActivityType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  AbstractActivityType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FfubarRequestId: Int64;
    FfubarRequestId_Specified: boolean;
    Fstate: ActivityState;
    Fstate_Specified: boolean;
    Fbegin_: TXSDateTime;
    Fend_: TXSDateTime;
    FvendorCode: string;
    Fnote: string;
    Fnote_Specified: boolean;
    FtripIdentifier: string;
    FtripIdentifier_Specified: boolean;
    Ffbo: ActivityFBOType;
    Ffbo_Specified: boolean;
    Fregulation: ActivityRegulationType;
    Fregulation_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SetfubarRequestId(Index: Integer; const AInt64: Int64);
    function  fubarRequestId_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setstate(Index: Integer; const AActivityState: ActivityState);
    function  state_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setnote(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  note_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure SettripIdentifier(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  tripIdentifier_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setfbo(Index: Integer; const AActivityFBOType: ActivityFBOType);
    function  fbo_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    procedure Setregulation(Index: Integer; const AActivityRegulationType: ActivityRegulationType);
    function  regulation_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property fubarRequestId: Int64                   Index (IS_ATTR or IS_OPTN) read FfubarRequestId write SetfubarRequestId stored fubarRequestId_Specified;
    property state:            ActivityState           Index (IS_OPTN) read Fstate write Setstate stored state_Specified;
    property begin_:           TXSDateTime             read Fbegin_ write Fbegin_;
    property end_:             TXSDateTime             read Fend_ write Fend_;
    property vendorCode:       string                  read FvendorCode write FvendorCode;
    property note:             string                  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fnote write Setnote stored note_Specified;
    property tripIdentifier:   string                  Index (IS_OPTN) read FtripIdentifier write SettripIdentifier stored tripIdentifier_Specified;
    property fbo:              ActivityFBOType         Index (IS_OPTN) read Ffbo write Setfbo stored fbo_Specified;
    property regulation:       ActivityRegulationType  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fregulation write Setregulation stored regulation_Specified;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : GuaranteeActivityType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  GuaranteeActivityType = class(AbstractActivityType)
  private
    Fduration: TXSDuration;
    Fairport: AirportType;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property duration: TXSDuration  read Fduration write Fduration;
    property airport:  AirportType  read Fairport write Fairport;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : GenericActivityType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  GenericActivityType = class(AbstractActivityType)
  private
    FstartAirport: AirportType;
    FendAirport: AirportType;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property startAirport: AirportType  read FstartAirport write FstartAirport;
    property endAirport:   AirportType  read FendAirport write FendAirport;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : PAXActivityType, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // ************************************************************************ //
  PAXActivityType = class(GenericActivityType)
  private
    Fpax: Integer;
  published
    property pax: Integer  read Fpax write Fpax;
  end;

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload
  // soapAction: http://www.fubar.com/integration/ScheduleUpload#request
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : document
  // use       : literal
  // binding   : ScheduleUploadWebServiceV2ImplPortBinding
  // service   : ScheduleUploadV2WS
  // port      : ScheduleUploadWebServiceV2ImplPort
  // URL       : https://development.fubar.com:443/fubar/fubarIntegrationWeb/ws/ScheduleUploadV2.ws
  // ************************************************************************ //
  ScheduleUploadV2WS = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{85B5395B-1FC2-0EB1-EDB6-1BDB3D2FFE23}']
    function  request(const schedules: ScheduleContainerType): StatusType; stdcall;
  end;

function GetScheduleUploadV2WS(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): ScheduleUploadV2WS;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;

function GetScheduleUploadV2WS(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): ScheduleUploadV2WS;
const
  defWSDL = 'https://development.fubar.com/fubar/fubarIntegrationWeb/ws/ScheduleUploadV2.ws?wsdl';
  defURL  = 'https://development.fubar.com:443/fubar/fubarIntegrationWeb/ws/ScheduleUploadV2.ws';
  defSvc  = 'ScheduleUploadV2WS';
  defPrt  = 'ScheduleUploadWebServiceV2ImplPort';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as ScheduleUploadV2WS);
    if UseWSDL then begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


destructor ScheduleType.Destroy;
var
  I: Integ
```

Comment: What is the .begin_ property all about?  I see one exposed property "pax" which is an integer...

Comment: @John - The pax- thing is a descendant of `AbstractActivityType`.   User - You're not assigning to 'begin_' property, you're assigning to `begin_.AsDateTime`. It's easy to check if `begin_` is 'assigned' or not at that time..

Comment: Sertac - the .begin_ property is nil (as in not Assigned()) - that's what's causing the access violation and hence my question.  I've created the myPaxActivity object so why would the .begin_ property be nil?

Comment: So the server side has an unassigned "begin_" object? What's up with that?

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating a PAXActivityType object doesn't automatically instantiate the begin_ TXSDateTime object (or any of its properties for that matter). You've either got to instantiate begin_ after you instantiate PAXActivityType or write some construction code into PAXActivityType that will do it for you in the constructor.

Comment: Sam - how do I instantiate begin_ ?

Comment: myPaxActivity.begin_ := TXSDateTime.Create;